# How do I add only specific elements in a multidimensional vector and print content to screen

Tags: c++, matrix

I was working on **matrixElementsSum** a task on codefights and more code seems okay to me but i am getting a subscript error in visual studio and the codefights compiler encounters a problem. I have no idea where i when wrong. Can i get some help

**Here is the problem:**

After becoming famous, CodeBots decided to move to a new building and live together. The building is represented by a rectangular matrix of rooms, each cell containing an integer - the price of the room. Some rooms are free (their cost is 0), but that's probably because they are haunted, so all the bots are afraid of them. That is why any room that is free or is located anywhere below a free room in the same column is not considered suitable for the bots.

Help the bots calculate the total price of all the rooms that are suitable for them.

Example

For

```
matrix = [[0, 1, 1, 2], 
         [0, 5, 0, 0], 
         [2, 0, 3, 3]]
```

the output should be
matrixElementsSum(matrix) = 9.

Here's the rooms matrix with unsuitable rooms marked with 'x':

```
[[x, 1, 1, 2], 
 [x, 5, x, x], 
 [x, x, x, x]]
```

Thus, the answer is 1 + 5 + 1 + 2 = 9.

**My solution** was to create a new matrix and output the newly created matrix (vectors) with only the elements I want then sum all elements and return the total.

```
int matrixElementsSum(std::vector<std::vector<int> > matrix) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > notHaunted;
    std::vector<int> room;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
        for (unsigned int  j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); j++) {
            //cout << matrix[i][j];

            if (matrix[i][j] == 0) {
                cout << " oooo its a haunted room... Lets see if there are more "
                     << endl;
            }
            else {
                room.push_back(j);
                notHaunted.push_back(room);
            }

            cout << notHaunted[i][j];
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    int total = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < notHaunted.size(); i++) {
        for (unsigned int  j = 0; j < notHaunted[i].size(); j++)
            total += notHaunted[i][j];
    }

    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   ....
    else
  {

    room.push_back(j);
    notHaunted.push_back(room);
  }

  cout << notHaunted[i][j]; //accessing out of bounds
}
```

Consider `i=0` and `j=0`, Your code goes in `if` part, so when printing `notHaunted[i][j]` , `notHaunted` is actually empty.So you are accessing out of bounds.
Moreover you are not handling the part where you mentioned rooms below a haunted room are also haunted.

A simple approach would be to first mark all haunted rooms as `0`.And then summing the entire array.